# How do you interpret the polynomial equation for the volume of a 3-D Washer?

Tags: geometry, volume

Can anyone explain what's going on in this formula for me?

Formulas:
[ (x^2 + y^2 ) > r1^2 ] , [ (x^2 + y^2 ) < r0^2 ] , [ z^2 < (h0/2)^2 ]

Formulas with constants filled in:
[ (x^2 + y^2 ) > 2^2 ] , [ (x^2 + y^2 ) < 10^2 ] , [ z^2 < (2/2)^2 ]

The formulas are supposedly describing the volume of a 3D Washer. I understand the first two terms are describing the volume of the 3D Washer exists between r1 and r0, but I don't understand where the [ z^2 < (h0/2)^2 ] part comes from. Perhaps it is describing the position of the washer in the z-direction, but I don't completely see it.

Any help with interpreting the formulas would be much appreciated.

Comment: These are not "formulas". You have written three inequalities defining the washer. The first two deal with the inner and outer radius. The third is the  height of the washer - the restriction on the $z$ coordinate. It makes no sense to multiply them.

Comment: Hi Ethan. The word "formula" is defined by Google's English Dictionary as "a mathematical relationship or rule expressed in symbols." I don't think gatekeeping mathematics is often productive, however, it is your own prerogative to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this definition,
the first two inequalities
describe a cylinder
with a smaller cylinder removed
and the third inequality
specifies the height
of the washer.

The third inequality is squared
so that the washer
is centered around the
x-y plane.
$z^2 < (h0/2)^2
$
is the same as
$|z| < h0/2$
so the total height
is $h0$
($h0/2$ above the x-y plane
and $h0/2$ below it.

Comment: Can you explain why the third inequality is squared?

Comment: Added the explanation.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.